# Insert Or update Kinesis stream data directly into Dynamodb without lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I was able to do this using lambda but, was facing some lagging issue, so is it possible to directly insert or update the data to DynamoDB, by using any aws services.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this use case by using the AWS SDK. Here is steps for this example:

1. Create a Kinesis Service Client.
2. Create a DynamoDB Service Client.
3. Call the Kinesis object's **getRecords** method.
4. This returns a collection of records.
5. Iterate through the record collection, read the record data,  and invoke the DynamoDB object's **putItem** method.

This is a high level description of how you can use the AWS SDK in a given programming language, such as Java, to read a Kinesis data stream and write the results to a DynamoDB table.

Comment: So  this can be done without using the aws lambda .. Can you provide any example  ?

Comment: I can write Java code for this use case if that will help

Comment: So where will I use that Java code. I do not want to create an aws lambda.